# How do I sum the data for 6 months ranges for 5 years for every employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, pivot

I am new to SQL programming and need your help.
I need to write a sql query that sums the amount every 6 months and cumulative sum of years  until 5 years,  for every employee starting from the day he joined the company.

My table looks like below

```
Employee    StartDate   DealDate    Amount
1           10/01/2017  11/01/2017  10000    --Starting month
1           10/01/2017  11/02/2017  15000    --within first 6 month of joining
1           10/01/2017  11/07/2017  20000    --6-12 months
1           10/01/2017  11/01/2018  30000    --12-18 months
1           10/01/2017  11/02/2018  40000    --12-18 months
1           10/01/2017  11/07/2018  50000    --18-24 months
1           10/01/2017  11/01/2019  60000    --24-30 months
1           10/01/2017  11/08/2019  70000    --30-36 months
1           10/01/2017  11/01/2020  80000    --36-42 months
1           10/01/2017  11/07/2020  90000    --42-48 months
2           20/01/2017  11/01/2017  10000    --so on for employee 2
2           20/01/2017  11/02/2017  25000
2           20/01/2017  11/07/2017  40000
2           20/01/2017  11/01/2018  30000
2           20/01/2017  11/02/2018  40000
2           20/01/2017  11/07/2018  50000
2           20/01/2017  11/01/2019  60000
2           20/01/2017  11/08/2019  70000
2           20/01/2017  11/01/2020  80000

and my expected outcome is

Employee    StartDate   [0-6month]  [6-12month] [1 year]    [12-18 month]   [18-24 month]   [2 year]
1           10/01/2017  25000       20000       45000       70000           50000           165000
2           20/01/2017  35000       40000       75000       70000           50000           195000
```

I tried the below

```
DECLARE @range1start DATE = @date
DECLARE @range1end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,6,@range1start))
DECLARE @range2start DATE = @range1end
DECLARE @range2end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,6,@range2start))
DECLARE @range3start DATE = @range2end
DECLARE @range3end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,12,@range3start)) '
```

And then using the case condition for every range. I was wondering if there is a better way of implementing this without using so many variables and loop. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation - although it is a bit lenghty to type:

```
select
    employee,
    min(startdate) startdate,
    sum(case when dealdate < dateadd(month, 6, startdate) then amount end) [0-6 month],
    sum(case when dealdate >= dateadd(month, 6, startdate) and dealdate < dateadd(month, 12, startdate) then amount end) [6-12 month],
    sum(case when dealdate < dateadd(month, 12, startdate) then amount end) [1 year],
    sum(case when dealdate >= dateadd(month, 12, startdate) and dealdate < dateadd(month, 18, startdate) then amount end) [12-18 month],
    sum(case when dealdate >= dateadd(month, 18, startdate) and dealdate < dateadd(month, 24, startdate) then amount end) [18-24 month],
    sum(case when dealdate >= dateadd(month, 12, startdate) and dealdate < dateadd(month, 24, startdate) then amount end) [2 year]
from mytable
group by employee
```